# mysql multiple "AND" condtions is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a query for getting friend list in mysql. The query is getting the result correctly.

This is the query I am using :

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT( * )               
        FROM
            cpo_conversation_reply               
        WHERE
            user_id_fk = u.id 
            AND user_id_rec = $user_id              
            AND read_unread_status =0  
            AND c.property_id = p_id
    ) AS unread_msg,
    u.id AS user_id, c.c_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.user_name,
    u.online_status AS loginstatus, c.user_one, c.user_two, u.user_img,
    c.property_id, p.locality, p.city, c.online_status          
FROM
    cpo_conversation c,
    property_register u,
    property_for_sale p          
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN c.user_one = '$user_id' THEN c.user_two = u.id                     
        WHEN c.user_two = '$user_id' THEN c.user_one = u.id                 
    END            
    AND (
        c.user_one = '$user_id' 
        OR c.user_two = '$user_id'               
    )                                     
    AND p.id = c.property_id           
ORDER BY
   c.c_id DESC
```

Now I want to hide the friends who's chat I have deleted..

For that I add following condition in and condition :

```
c.hide_chat_1 != '1' OR c.hide_chat_2 != '1'
```

after, this query is like this :

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT( * )                  
        FROM
            cpo_conversation_reply                  
        WHERE
            user_id_fk = u.id 
            AND user_id_rec = $user_id                  
            AND read_unread_status =0  
            AND c.property_id = p_id                  
    ) AS unread_msg,
    u.id AS user_id, c.c_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.user_name,
    u.online_status AS loginstatus, c.user_one, c.user_two, u.user_img,
    c.property_id, p.locality, p.city, c.online_status                  
FROM
    cpo_conversation c,
    property_register u,
    property_for_sale p                  
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN c.user_one = '$user_id' THEN c.user_two = u.id                  
        WHEN c.user_two = '$user_id' THEN c.user_one = u.id                  
    END 
    AND (
        c.user_one = '$user_id'                  
        OR c.user_two = '$user_id'                  
    )                   
    AND (
        c.hide_chat_1 != '1'                  
        OR c.hide_chat_2 != '1'                  
    )                  
    AND p.id = c.property_id                  
ORDER BY
    c.c_id DESC
```

But it is not hiding the friends who hide chat status is `1`.

Can anybody help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
c.hide_chat_1 <> '1'
OR c.hide_chat_2 <> '1'
```

Comment: @Azad Chouhan What are c.hide_chat_1 and c.hide_chat_2 defined as?  If they are numeric types it should be `c.hide_chat_1 <> 1 or c.hide_chat_2 <> 1`  No quotes.

Comment: yes its numeric and I am using as numeric but still its show me all record . I want to show records who's hide_chat_1 or hide_chat_2 is 0